# Animated Refresh icon

Tags: android, animation, refresh, android-animation

The plan is for the refresh icon to starts animating when the user clicks on the refresh icon, however, there seems to be an error when I implement the animation function; "The method loadAnimation(Context, int) in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int)".

Below is the code snippet. How do I load the Animation from the Animation Source, without the above error while still retaining the onClickListener framework.

```
    final ImageView refreshBtn= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spin_refresh);
    Log.i("RootActivity:setupHeader","******ImageView refreshBtn******");
    //Listening to Button Click by User
    refreshBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //To set new INTENT on calling Methods in UPDATE & DOWNLOADSERVICE 
            .....

            //Perform Refresh Animation
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);

            //ISSUE IS AT .loadAnimation not able to be implemented.
            Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_refresh);
            rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            iv.startAnimation(rotation);
            item.setActionView(iv);

            //ALERT DIALOG TO INFORM USER THAT REFRESH FUNCTION HAS BEEN CALLED
            .......
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_refresh);
```

to

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(YourActivity.this, R.anim.rotate_refresh);
```

The reason is that at that point in your code, `this` refers to `View.OnClickListener`, not to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

this refers to OnclickListner there

change it to your context

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_refresh);
```